# Set default editor for Android XML files

Tags: android, eclipse

I just updated the ADT plugin for Eclipse and now my Android Layout XML files open in the default XML editor, not the Layout Editor, and I can't find out where or how to fix it. I would also like the other Android XML files to open in the correct editors, not just Layout files, without having to resort to opening with right click -> open with -> select editor.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Or why it changed?

** EDIT **
Have added a bug report - If this is happening with you too please star it or add a comment - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21004&q=adt&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: You sure you dont just have the XML tag selected? (bottom-left) :)

Answer (score 3):

Customize Eclipse's actions with different file types and what to open them with in [Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations].

There, you'll have to either select a file extension, or add one to the list and choose what program/editor, may it be one of Eclipse's, or one of your own installed programs, to open it with whenever it's encountered.

Note that this is for Eclipse Juno v4.2.0. Not sure if it's the exact same for other versions of Eclipse, but it can't hurt to try, right?